# Remove elements from div

Tags: jquery

I wonder how do I always remove the last element of the div until there is only one element, the code follows below.
I'm already able to do so later add it now is missing remove.

```
$("#add").click(function()
{
    $("#divparent").append($("#divchild").html());
});
$("#remove").click(function()
{
   //new code
});
```

```
<div id="divparent">
    <div id="divchild">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" Width="270"></asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is really difficult to understand what you're asking because of how this question is worded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do a few things.

- I strongly advise you to not append an Item with the same ID as something else. Change it to a Class
- if this is an asp based list and items are added dynamically you may want to look into [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)
- I would [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)() `.divchild` and not appened the child. Notice how I modified the add function

  - notice on `.clone()` that the default value is false, you may want to consider true, but should investigate this to fit your solution dependant on what is in your asp drop down list.

live example: http://jsfiddle.net/JWFu5/

```
$("#add").click(function() {
    $('.divchild:last').clone(true).fadeIn().insertAfter($('.divchild:last'));
});
$("#remove").click(function() {
    var count = $('.divchild').length;
    if (count > 1) {
        $('.divchild:last').fadeOut().detach()
    }
    else {
        alert('You Must Have At Least One Child');
    }
});
```

Comment: This clones the entire div instead of just its content as in the question, but I guess that must be what OP actually wanted.

Comment: It is hard to tell, but it seemed this seems logical. Otherwise you are just appending the html of the div without any of its retained style or functionality. see: http://jsfiddle.net/r4kXr/ which uses the add function of the OP. it does not appear to be what one would want. But I concede it is hard to tell.

Comment: Yeah, I can't really tell either. I assume this is a `<select>` element, so there probably isn't any inline style (should be in a style sheet anyway). With respect to functionality, for dynamic elements like this, event delegation with `.delegate()` or `.live()` should probably be used, but like you said, it's hard to tell.

Comment: ...anyway +1 for dealing with potential issues.

Answer (score 5):

First of all you don't want to give all the children the same id.

This should work for you:

```
$("#remove").click(function()
{
    $('#divparent').find(':last-child').not(':only-child').remove();
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/Srfk2/

Comment: I'm torn, I want to -1 you for ignoring his request to leave at least one element, but want to +1 you for being the only answer besides mine to see that he is inserting a child with a duped ID =)

Comment: @matchew: Does the `ID` in the asp code translate to an `id` attribute? I don't know how asp works.

Comment: that is a good question, I too am unfamiliar to ASP, in fact Ignored that line in my answer, but I would assume so.

Comment: no problem. +1 for having a working answer, more or less, before me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#remove").click(function()
{
   if($('#divparent > div').length > 1){
          $('#divparent').find(':last-child').remove();
   }
});
```

to remove last till there is one left